# Same related products throughout the website - Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have a Ecommerce website having lots of products. When I am going to choose related product for one specific product it's automatically showing in all products as related product.

How can I fix this?

I need to have different related products in different products.

Answer (score 1):

It will show the products related to the search criteria in that grid(first time it will show all the products) and you have to choose the products which are related to that specific product from that list by click the checkbox given there and click save button to get that list as your related products